# GROUP BY All Values From One Column in a Table, With Averages From Another Table. Error: FROM-clause

Tags: sql, group-by, psql

I am trying to retrieve the average score for every main_url. However, each score, is identified by a post_id, and each post is associated with a main_url.

However, I am getting an odd error message:

```
 ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "post"
LINE 1: ..._url_id LEFT JOIN score c ON b.post_id = c.post....
                                                    ^
```

I do not understand, since I do have a FROM clause. And all the other LEFT JOIN query's I have written have only required the single FROM clause.

The 'total' value, is in the score TABLE.

This is my query:

```
 `
SELECT main_url, AVG(total)
FROM main_url a 
LEFT JOIN post b ON a.main_url_id = b.main_url_id
LEFT JOIN score c ON b.post_id = c.post.id
GROUP BY main_url
`
```

These are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE main_url(
    main_url_id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    main_url      VARCHAR(2100)
);



CREATE TABLE post(
    post_id       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    post_title    VARCHAR (2100),
    author_id     INTEGER,
    post_url      VARCHAR(2100),
    main_url_id   INTEGER 
);



CREATE TABLE score(
    score_id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    detail      INTEGER,
    prose       INTEGER,
    s_g         INTEGER,
    like_it     INTEGER,
    total       INTEGER,
    post_id     INTEGER,
    account_id  INTEGER
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `main_url` is unique, I would recommend aggregating by the id rather than the url itself -- that should be much more efficient.

Also, use table abbreviations for aliases, not arbitrary letters.  And qualify all column references.  So:

```
SELECT mu.main_url, AVG(s.total)
FROM main_url mu LEFT JOIN
     post p
     ON p.main_url_id = mu.main_url_id LEFT JOIN
     score s
     ON s.post_id = p.post.id
GROUP BY  mu.main_url_id;
```

If `main_url` is not unique, then in `main_url`, then you need to aggregate by that column.  However, if you can avoid aggregating on a string with up to thousands of characters, you are better off avoiding it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join with c.post_id

```
SELECT main_url, AVG(total)
FROM main_url a 
LEFT JOIN post b ON a.main_url_id = b.main_url_id
LEFT JOIN score c ON b.post_id = c.post_id
GROUP BY main_url
```